# conditional regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I need to create an IF clause that would catch all strings that are in the following format:

`Pharm` followed by any letter followed by any three digits.

For example, `Pharmf750` or `Pharmc648`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the simplest regexp ever. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you need is `/^Pharm[A-Za-z][0-9]{3}$/`.

Try something like

```
if (preg_match('/^Pharm[A-Za-z][0-9]{3}$/', $stringToMatch) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple

```
/^Pharm[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}$/
```